# How to get the value of clock cycles in ticks using linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, timer, clock

Taking the timestamp in linux is same as clock cycles in ticks for linux. 
I know how to get the timestamp but I dont now how to take the clock cycles in ticks.
could someone tell me what is the difference between the two ??
could someone give me a small example for clock cycles in ticks ??

Looking forward for your reply.

extra : Am trying to add assembly instructions for timing in pisa architecture using simplescalar simulator. For my instructions i should access clock cycles and store it in the register.

Comment: Most modern CPUs have clocks whose frequency varies dynamically according to demand, temperature, etc, so counting CPU clock cycles is pretty tough - you generally need to access CPU performance registers for this.

Comment: thank you for the reply. could you please give me a small example ?

Comment: It depends on what CPU you are using and what kind of access you have to performance registers - there is no simple "one size fits all" answer to this AFAIK.

Comment: BTW, please confirm whether you want CPU clock cycles, or do you just want elapsed time converted to ticks (which is just a unit conversion) ?

Comment: the below answer suggest me to use clock_gettime. but how to add that to the performance register ??

Comment: Please clarify what it is that you actually want - elapsed time or CPU clocks ?

Comment: I want CPU clock cycles.

Comment: OK - but you also mentioned "ticks" - maybe you could specify more clearly what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: OK - I see the reference to using a simulator - do you want simulator clock cycles or host CPU clock cycles ?

Comment: I want to access the simulator clock cycle

Comment: OK - that's a very different question from what you originally asked.

Comment: could you please give me a small example ??

Comment: You'll need to read the documentation for your simulator to find out how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Well, there are:

1. [Ticks. Modern kernels don't use them](http://lwn.net/Articles/549580/).
2. [Timestamp counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter), this is what you may like to use for high-resolution time measurements, but you have to understand how to make unbiased measurements with it.
3. Clocks, portable `clock_gettime`, nanosecond-resolution, often good enough for everything.

If you want to get access to CPU performance registers, you can start with [Intel® Performance Counter Monitor inside your programs](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor-a-better-way-to-measure-cpu-utilization#calling_pcm).

Comment: I use clock_gettime to get the time. but how to add that to the performance register ??

Comment: @PaulR clock cycles are meaningless on super-scalar CPUs because it may execute more than one instruction in one cycle, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_performance_counter#Instruction_based_sampling

Comment: thank you for the reply. I extended my question, could you please give me a small example ?

Comment: @user3629652 Added a link for you.